# Typescript: how to upload multiple image on one request?

Tags: java, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

HTML:

```
<div>
  <input 
    type ="file" 
    (change)="selectFiles($event)" 
    multiple="multiple" />
</div>
```

Function calling the change event

```
selectFiles(event) {
  const reader = new FileReader();

  if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length) {
    const [file] = event.target.files;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    reader.onload = () => {
      this.myModel.get('propertyName').setValue({
        fileName: file.name,
        fileContent: reader.result
      });
    };
  }
}
```

This gives me one selected file , How to get multiple file content on one request?

Comment: Where exactly are you storing these files? What is your Backend and what does it accept?

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera It is java. The fileContent is stored in database and it is  of type ' Blob '.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using array-destructuring (`const [file] = event.target.files`) you only read the first file in `event.target.files`. Instead, just use the `event.target.files` array itself, and then upload all the files using `FormData`.

component.html:

```
<div>
  <input type="file" (change)="selectFiles($event)" multiple="multiple" />
</div>
```

component.ts:

```
private files: File[];

constructor(/* ... */, private backend: MyBackendService) {
  /* ... */
}

public selectFiles(event: Event): void {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length) {
    this.files = event.target.files;
  }
}

// call this when you're done filling your form, usually on (ngSubmit)
public submitForm(): void {
  this.backend.uploadFiles(this.files);
}
```

backend.service.ts

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    /* ... */
}

uploadFiles(files: File[]): void {
    const formData = new FormData();
    files.forEach((file) => formData.append(/* your field's name */, file));
    this.http.post</* your response type */>(/* your API endpoint URL */, formData).subscribe(/* handle response */);
}
```

Please read [this gist](https://gist.github.com/WebReflection/f04425ce4cfeb18d75236cb50255e4bc) for further information.